# How to enable bullet points when using the presento beamer theme?

Tags: beamer, itemize, themes

I have the problem that when I use an `itemize` list and the [presento `beamer` theme](https://github.com/RatulSaha/presento), there are no bullet points.

Here is a minimal working example (requires the [linked theme](https://github.com/RatulSaha/presento) not available on CTAN to be downloaded first):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{config/presento}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item ...
\item ...
\item ...
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: example output of an itemize list without bullet points]

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\usepackage{enumitem}` has to be removed from `presento.sty`, it is incompatible with beamer.

(related issue on github: https://github.com/RatulSaha/presento/issues/6)

Comment: what package do you recommend to use instead of _enumitem_  in beamer?

Comment: @Another.Chemist Don't use any other package and let beamer do the work. With `mini templates` and such you can modify the appearance of enumerations without any other package.

Answer (score 0):

Well, testing various modifications to the template configuration files and I fixed my problem.

I commented that lines in 'presento.sty' file

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
...
...
\newenvironment{baseitemize}
  {\itemize[leftmargin=*]}
  {\enditemize}

\newenvironment{fullpageitemize}
  {\itemize[nolistsep,itemsep=\fill,leftmargin=*]}
  {\vfill\enditemize}
```

regards